# Sqlite rounding time down

Tags: sqlite, rounding

is it possibile rounding time to nearest 5 minutes down?
Something like that:
select datetime('now')
return 2017-05-09 07:34:26

Select stuffcodesql
return 2017-05-09 05:00:00

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Get current datetime as unix timestamp
   `strftime('%s', 'now')`
2. Subtract the remainder of the division by 300 (300 seconds or 5 minutes)
   `strftime('%s', 'now') % 300`
3. Convert to local time format
   `select datetime(strftime('%s', 'now') - strftime('%s', 'now') % 300, 'unixepoch', 'localtime') as [5min];`

Answer (score 1):

1. Convert the timestamp into a number of days;
2. multiply by 288 (the number of 5-minute intervals per day);
3. round down to the nearest integer;
4. divide by 288 again;
5. convert back into a string:

```
SELECT datetime(CAST(julianday('now') * 288 AS INTEGER) / 288.0);
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work (returns 2017-05-08 12:00:00 while it's 2017-05-09 today)

Comment: That is the correct time, in UTC. Add the `'localtime'` modifier to the `datetime()` call if you want to see the result in your local time zone.

Comment: `SELECT datetime(CAST(julianday('now') * 288 AS INTEGER) / 288.0,'localtime');` gives me 2017-05-08 14:00:00

Comment: The SELECTs from both our answers give the same result for me.