# SQLite Query for a 5 minutes Time Bucket Column from DATETIME column values

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

**This requirement is for SQLite database.**

I've created a table like below.

```
-- Create TABLE
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TABLE3;
CREATE TABLE TABLE3 (
    DATETIME TEXT,
    TIME_BUCKET TEXT
);

-- Insert data into TABLE
INSERT INTO TABLE3 (DATETIME, TIME_BUCKET) VALUES
('2024-01-09T10:33:06.987',''),
('2024-01-09T10:33:06.987',''),
('2024-01-09T10:34:07.006',''),
('2024-01-09T10:38:07.161',''),
('2024-01-09T10:39:10.061',''),
('2024-01-09T10:40:21.279',''),
('2024-01-09T10:44:21.317',''),
('2024-01-09T10:49:21.448',''),
('2024-01-09T10:51:05.673','');

-- Select data from Table
SELECT * FROM TABLE3;
DATETIME    TIME_BUCKET
2024-01-09T10:33:06.987 
2024-01-09T10:33:06.987 
2024-01-09T10:34:07.006 
2024-01-09T10:38:07.161 
2024-01-09T10:39:10.061 
2024-01-09T10:40:21.279 
2024-01-09T10:44:21.317 
2024-01-09T10:49:21.448 
2024-01-09T10:51:05.673
```

Now I could update the TIME_BUCKET column to have 1 minute time bucket values, like below.

```
UPDATE TABLE3
SET TIME_BUCKET = strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:00', DATETIME);

SELECT * FROM TABLE3;
DATETIME    TIME_BUCKET
2024-01-09T10:33:06.987 2024-01-09 10:33:00
2024-01-09T10:33:06.987 2024-01-09 10:33:00
2024-01-09T10:34:07.006 2024-01-09 10:34:00
2024-01-09T10:38:07.161 2024-01-09 10:38:00
2024-01-09T10:39:10.061 2024-01-09 10:39:00
2024-01-09T10:40:21.279 2024-01-09 10:40:00
2024-01-09T10:44:21.317 2024-01-09 10:44:00
2024-01-09T10:49:21.448 2024-01-09 10:49:00
2024-01-09T10:51:05.673 2024-01-09 10:51:00
```

But I could not  update the TIME_BUCKET column to have a 5 minutes time bucket.
I tried below query, but it did set the values of TIME_BUCKET column to NULL.

```
UPDATE TABLE3
SET TIME_BUCKET = strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:00', DATETIME, 'start of minute', '+5 minutes');
```

*With strftime, 'start of day/month/year' works; but 'start of minute/hour' not working.*

Basically I want the output like below

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE3;
DATETIME    TIME_BUCKET
2024-01-09T10:33:06.987 2024-01-09 10:30:00
2024-01-09T10:33:06.987 2024-01-09 10:30:00
2024-01-09T10:34:07.006 2024-01-09 10:30:00
2024-01-09T10:38:07.161 2024-01-09 10:35:00
2024-01-09T10:39:10.061 2024-01-09 10:35:00
2024-01-09T10:40:21.279 2024-01-09 10:40:00
2024-01-09T10:44:21.317 2024-01-09 10:40:00
2024-01-09T10:49:21.448 2024-01-09 10:45:00
2024-01-09T10:51:05.673 2024-01-09 10:50:00
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43861890/sqlite-rounding-time-down

Answer (score 0):

Below SQLite query did work

```
UPDATE TABLE3
SET TIME_BUCKET = strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:00', strftime('%s', DATETIME) / 300 * 300, 'unixepoch') AS TIME_BUCKET;
```

In this query, strftime('%s', DATETIME) converts the DATETIME to seconds since the epoch, and then integer division and multiplication are performed to round down to the nearest 5-minute interval. Finally, strftime with 'unixepoch' is used for formatting.